# Distance between matched substrings

Tags: string, perl, substring, distance

I have a chromosome sequence and have to find subsequences in it and the distances between them.

For example:

string:

> AACCGGTTACGTTTGGCCAAACGTTTTTTGGGGAAACCCACGTACGTAAAGCCGGTTAAACGT

Substring:

> ACGT

I have to find the distance between all occurrences of `ACGT`.

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO is not a code writing service. You need to try first, and ask about a specific problem. I generally do not recommend answering posts when it is obvious the OP just wants other people to do their work.

Comment: What do you mean by "distance between"? What results do you expect from this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally do not recommend answering posts where it is obvious the OP just wants other people to do their work. However, there is already one answer the use of which will be problematic if input strings are largish, so here is something that uses Perl builtins.

The special variable [`@-`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#@LAST_MATCH_START) stores the positions of matches after a pattern matches.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $string = 'AACCGGTTACGTTTGGCCAAACGTTTTTTGGGGAAACCCACGTACGTAAAGCCGGTTAAACGT';

my @pos;

while ( $string =~ /ACGT/g ) {
    push @pos, $-[0];
}

my @dist;

for my $i (1 .. $#pos) {
    push @dist, $pos[$i] - $pos[$i - 1];
}

print Dumper(\@pos, \@dist);
```

This method uses less memory than splitting the original string (which may be a problem if the original string is large enough). Its memory footprint can be further reduced, but I focused on clarity by showing the accumulation of match positions and the calculation of deltas separately.

One open question is whether you want the index of the first match from the beginning of the string. Strictly speaking, "distances between matches" excludes that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $string = 'AACCGGTTACGTTTGGCCAAACGTTTTTTGGGGAAACCCACGTACGTAAAGCCGGTTAAACGT';

my @dist;
my $last;

while ($string =~ /ACGT/g) {
    no warnings 'uninitialized';
    push @dist, $-[0] - $last;
    $last = $-[0];
}

# Do we want the distance of the first
# match from the beginning of the string?

shift @dist;

print Dumper \@dist;
```

Of course, it is possible to use `index` for this as well, but it looks considerably uglier.

Comment: That's pretty much what I would write. But we don't really know what the OP means by *distance between*, and they are quite likely to want the number of bases from the start of one subsequence to the start of the next.

Comment: It's easy to add 4 if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

You may `split` your input string by `"ACGT"` and remove the first and the last elements of the returned array to get all fragments between `"ACGT"`. Then calculate lengths of this fragments:

```
my $input = "AACCGGTTACGTTTGGCCAAACGTTTTTTGGGGAAACCCACGTACGTAAAGCCGGTTAAACGT";
my @fragments = split("ACGT", $input, -1);
@fragments = @fragments[1..$#fragments - 1];
my @dist_arr = map {length} @fragments;
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/AqEwGu